# How to unsupervised-cluster of binary vectors?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, distance-functions

I have a set of binary vectors of roughly 500 dimensions. For EDA purposes mainly, I'd like to cluster them, maybe hierarchically.

What could be the right distance metric for my problem?
Is the number of dimensions prone to the curse of dimensionality?

It is worth mentioning that most of the values are 0s and a few are set to 1 (most of the time 1-3 1s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of distance metric is *very* domain specific.

For example the Jaccard index is a classic similarity for presence data.

But given that you have just about 3 bits of information per vector I am not convinced that you'll be able to get much beyond counting frequent values and pairs. You'll have too man exact same distances because of your low data resolution.

Comment: I see. Thank you